# Unable to locate the element using CSS_SELECTOR in selenium using python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I've been trying to locate and click() a javascript rendered image.
Using css_selector I'm able to locate the element, however, I have to hover over the 1st element of the table in order to capture the location of the image.

```
<tbody>
<tr __gwt_row="0" __gwt_subrow="0" class="GPBYFDECG">
    <td class="GPBYFDEBG GPBYFDEDG GPBYFDEEG datagridCellStyle"><div style="outline-style:none;" __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-6847" tabindex="0">ACD CALL DETAILS NEW</div></td>
    <td class="GPBYFDEBG GPBYFDEDG datagridCellStyle"><div style="outline-style:none;" __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-6848">sup001</div></td>
    <td class="GPBYFDEBG GPBYFDEDG datagridCellStyle"><div style="outline-style:none;" __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-6849">2019-01-22 01:05:57</div></td>
    <td class="GPBYFDEBG GPBYFDEDG datagridCellStyle"><div style="outline-style:none;" __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-6850"><img onload="this.__gwtLastUnhandledEvent=&quot;load&quot;;" src="http://172.00.00.00.00:8889/ameyoreports/AmeyoReportsApp/clear.cache.gif" style="width:16px;height:16px;background:url(http://172.00.00.00:8889/ameyoreports/AmeyoReportsApp/0210CFCB6CBE82D7E9FAC82D9F901495.cache.png) no-repeat -308px -25px;" border="0"></div></td>
    <td class="GPBYFDEBG GPBYFDEDG datagridCellStyle"><div style="outline-style:none;" __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-6851">SUCCESS</div></td><td class="GPBYFDEBG GPBYFDEDG datagridCellStyle"><div style="outline-style:none;" __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-6852"></div></td>
    <td class="GPBYFDEBG GPBYFDEDG gwt-Clickable-Custom"><div style="outline-style:none;" __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-6853"><img onload="this.__gwtLastUnhandledEvent=&quot;load&quot;;" src="http://172.00.00.00.00/ameyoreports/AmeyoReportsApp/clear.cache.gif" style="width:24px;height:24px;background:url(http://172.00.00.00:8889/ameyoreports/AmeyoReportsApp/0210CFCB6CBE82D7E9FAC82D9F901495.cache.png) no-repeat -406px 0px;" border="0"></div></td>
    <td class="GPBYFDEBG GPBYFDEDG gwt-Clickable-Custom"><div style="outline-style:none;" __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-6854"></div></td><td class="GPBYFDEBG GPBYFDEDG"><div style="outline-style:none;" __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-6855"></div></td><td class="GPBYFDEBG GPBYFDEDG GPBYFDEOG gwt-Clickable-Custom"><div style="outline-style:none;" __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-6856"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr __gwt_row="1" __gwt_subrow="0" class="GPBYFDEBH">
<td class="GPBYFDEBG GPBYFDECH GPBYFDEEG datagridCellStyle"><div style="outline-style:none;" __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-601">ACD CALL DETAILS NEW</div></td>
    <td class="GPBYFDEBG GPBYFDECH datagridCellStyle"><div style="outline-style:none;" __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-602">Administrator</div></td>
    <td class="GPBYFDEBG GPBYFDECH datagridCellStyle"><div style="outline-style:none;" __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-603">2019-01-22 18:06:58</div></td>
    <td class="GPBYFDEBG GPBYFDECH datagridCellStyle"><div style="outline-style:none;" __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-604"><img onload="this.__gwtLastUnhandledEvent=&quot;load&quot;;" src="http://172.00.00.00:8889/ameyoreports/AmeyoReportsApp/clear.cache.gif" style="width:16px;height:16px;background:url(http://172.00.00.00:8889/ameyoreports/AmeyoReportsApp/0210CFCB6CBE82D7E9FAC82D9F901495.cache.png) no-repeat -308px -25px;" border="0"></div></td>
    <td class="GPBYFDEBG GPBYFDECH datagridCellStyle"><div style="outline-style:none;" __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-605">SUCCESS</div></td><td class="GPBYFDEBG GPBYFDECH datagridCellStyle"><div style="outline-style:none;" __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-606"></div></td>
    <td class="GPBYFDEBG GPBYFDECH gwt-Clickable-Custom"><div style="outline-style:none;" __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-607"><img onload="this.__gwtLastUnhandledEvent=&quot;load&quot;;" src="http://172.00.00.00:8889/ameyoreports/AmeyoReportsApp/clear.cache.gif" style="width:24px;height:24px;background:url(http://172.00.00.00:8889/ameyoreports/AmeyoReportsApp/0210CFCB6CBE82D7E9FAC82D9F901495.cache.png) no-repeat -406px 0px;" border="0"></div></td>
    <td class="GPBYFDEBG GPBYFDECH gwt-Clickable-Custom"><div style="outline-style:none;" __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-608"></div></td><td class="GPBYFDEBG GPBYFDECH"><div style="outline-style:none;" __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-609"></div></td><td class="GPBYFDEBG GPBYFDECH GPBYFDEOG gwt-Clickable-Custom"><div style="outline-style:none;" __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-610"></div</td>
</tr>
<tr __gwt_row="2" __gwt_subrow="0" class="GPBYFDECG">
    <td class="GPBYFDEBG GPBYFDEDG GPBYFDEEG datagridCellStyle"><div style="outline-style:none;" __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-6847" tabindex="0">ACD CALL DETAILS NEW</div></td>
    <td class="GPBYFDEBG GPBYFDEDG datagridCellStyle"><div style="outline-style:none;" __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-6848">sup001</div></td>
    <td class="GPBYFDEBG GPBYFDEDG datagridCellStyle"><div style="outline-style:none;" __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-6849">2019-01-22 01:05:57</div></td>
    <td class="GPBYFDEBG GPBYFDEDG datagridCellStyle"><div style="outline-style:none;" __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-6850"><img onload="this.__gwtLastUnhandledEvent=&quot;load&quot;;" src="http://172.16.10.23:8889/ameyoreports/AmeyoReportsApp/clear.cache.gif" style="width:16px;height:16px;background:url(http://172.00.00.00:8889/ameyoreports/AmeyoReportsApp/0210CFCB6CBE82D7E9FAC82D9F901495.cache.png) no-repeat -308px -25px;" border="0"></div></td>
    <td class="GPBYFDEBG GPBYFDEDG datagridCellStyle"><div style="outline-style:none;" __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-6851">SUCCESS</div></td><td class="GPBYFDEBG GPBYFDEDG datagridCellStyle"><div style="outline-style:none;" __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-6852"></div></td>
    <td class="GPBYFDEBG GPBYFDEDG gwt-Clickable-Custom"><div style="outline-style:none;" __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-6853"><img onload="this.__gwtLastUnhandledEvent=&quot;load&quot;;" src="http://172.16.10.23:8889/ameyoreports/AmeyoReportsApp/clear.cache.gif" style="width:24px;height:24px;background:url(http://172.00.00.00:8889/ameyoreports/AmeyoReportsApp/0210CFCB6CBE82D7E9FAC82D9F901495.cache.png) no-repeat -406px 0px;" border="0"></div></td>
    <td class="GPBYFDEBG GPBYFDEDG gwt-Clickable-Custom"><div style="outline-style:none;" __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-6854"></div></td><td class="GPBYFDEBG GPBYFDEDG"><div style="outline-style:none;" __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-6855"></div></td><td class="GPBYFDEBG GPBYFDEDG GPBYFDEOG gwt-Clickable-Custom"><div style="outline-style:none;" __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-6856"></div></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Now, I need to click on the 7th child of the first row, which changes dynamically. First, It will be a different image and after processing, it will be a PNG button which can be clicked and the reports can be downloaded.

By using the code below I was able to find the required element. However, I had to manually hover over the first row in order to do so. Additionally, If I hover over 2nd or 3rd row accidentally, content of 2nd and 3rd row will be downloaded instead of first.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".GPBYFDEKG:nth-child(7) img"))).click()
```

Is there any way I can click on the 7th child of first row whithout manually hover over it?

Comment: You can automate the mouse hovering work with selenium using api like `move_to_element`.

Comment: Class names and values are same. Please, have a look at the snippet and help me with the code to hover over 7th child of first row. I'm kind of new in selenium.

Comment: looks like last  2 blocks of html are same as first block of 7 lines, is that  or you want to hover over all 3 elements from every blocks 7th row

Comment: @Sourav, You can use xpath like `//tbody/tr[1]/td[7]`, just add correct xpath for your table as per full html before this.

Comment: @Dev,  I just want to hover over 1st block(1st row). I can see that all the <tr> tags have different __gwt_row number. Can I use __gwt_row="0" in some way to uniquely identify and hover over the element?
If Yes, can you help me with an example to do the same.

Comment: @Kamal, Surely will try that. It's giving me a very hard time.

Comment: Can I generate XPATH using    .gwt_row='0' .GPBYFDEKG:nth-child(7) img 
The approach will be to first identify the 1st row using .gwt_row='0' and then perform a click on  .GPBYFDEKG:nth-child(7) img.

Could you help me with the correct syntax to do the same.

Comment: @sourav, could you please share the url?

Comment: @Kajal, This is a restricted portal only used in our office. I'm afraid I won't be able to share the credentials.
However, based on the snippet provided in the question if you could help me with the requirement, then it would be great.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it will work in Python or not but you can try the below XPaths:

```
//tr[@__gwt_row='0']/td[last()]
```

or

```
(//tr[@__gwt_row='0']/td)[7]
```

Comment: When I run the above snippet, It locates the element successfully. however instead on clicking on the image it displays error   "stale element reference element is not attached to the page document"

Comment: Give some delay before clicking or check some conditions like wait until the element is visible or clickable... Try to use FluentWait to avoid some exceptions while performing an operations on the web element

Comment: I have already used      "WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//tr[@__gwt_row='0']/td)[7]"))).click()

Comment: Try this:`wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60, poll_frequency=5, ignored_exceptions=[ElementNotVisibleException, StaleElementReferenceException]);
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//tr[@__gwt_row='0']/td)[7]"))); element.click();`